# WebBrowser Control insert word in caret position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF `WebBrowser` control where I need to insert some text (e.g. the selected item coming from a listbox). This way, if the editor contains "When " and the listbox contains "I, You, He" and I click on "You", the editor must contain "When you".

The code I'm using with the `ActiveElement` is working right now, but I'm finding some weird issues explained below.

```
HTMLDocument doc;
doc = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
doc.activeElement.innerHTML += " " + selectedItemFromListboxAsString + " ";
```

Then, the webbrowser gets appended the `selectedItemFromListboxAsString` properly, but when I continue typing after that, the new keystrokes go to the next line. In the sourcecode I can see that a `</P>` tag has been put after the `selectedItemFromListboxAsString`. No matter if I remove the `</P>` programmatically, it will insert the new typed content in a new line.

Is there any other way to achieve the same result instead of playing around with the `activeElement`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using the `innerText` property instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: I tried to do activeElement.innerText += ... but in that case, I'm losing the formats (bold, italic, or whatever)

Comment: @BorjaLópez It's better to share a sample content to reproduce the problem.